# Rescalling a design for Android UI

Tags: gui-design, android, responsive-design

How can I rescalle an mdpi design for Android UI to other resolutions in Photoshop? And is there any app for Win to do that in real time (like Skala)?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Photoshop CC, Adobe included the "Generate" function, which will, in real time, generate resources from your Layers in configurable sizes and file types.

There is an introduction on the Photoshop blog here:

[Introducing Adobe Generator for Photoshop CC](https://blogs.adobe.com/photoshop/2013/09/introducing-adobe-generator-for-photoshop-cc.html)

This is all done by simply naming your layers and a good way to export your Assets for different screen sizes. Does this answer your question?